# GPU Timings with OpenGL on MacOSX

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I need the timespan it took to deal with a set of drawing calls on the gpu-side. OpenGL 3.2+ has the "GL_ARB_timer_query"-extension for that. Unfortunately MacOSX still doesn;t support that extension.

How would you be able to measure time on the gpu-side, there must be an old-fashioned way or different way to do that.

Comment: You don't even need GL 3.2 (where it isn't an extension but part of the core, anyway) for `ARB_timer_query`. I even had it on my 2.1-only 7850GT, but well it wasn't a Mac ;)

Comment: Can you evaluate more? As far as I'm aware the extension is completely unavailable...

Comment: Like said, I don't know about the situation with MacOSX as I never worked with it. I just wanted to say, that you don't need GL 3.2 hardware or drivers for the `ARB_timer_query` extension, well as long as the hardware and drivers support the extension, which is completely decoupled from GL 3.2 (where it is no extension anyway, but a core feature).

Answer (score 2):

> How would you be able to measure time on the gpu-side, there must be an old-fashioned way or different way to do that.

Why must there be one? Indeed, ARB_timer_query exists because there was *never* a way to time GPU operations. That's what it's for, and it is the only accurate mechanism OpenGL has to do it.

There have always been general profiling techniques, like changing resolution to test to see if you're "fillrate" bound or not and so forth. But there is no way to actually measure GPU processing time in OpenGL other than ARB_timer_query.

Answer (score 1):

Won't `glFinish()` with a host side timer work?

Comment: Well it will at least be a problem when the draw calls are not last operations you want to perform, or when you just don't want to stall the whole pipeline or block the whole CPU application. But Ok, for a dedicated test run, maybe.

Comment: then I would have to run glFinish and the host side timer in a seperate thread, because otherwise I would force another synchronisation point between mainthread and gpu, if I am thinking this straight. I need the gpu timings the next frame not on the same frame, so this synchronisation point would be unnecessary. I may should've mentioned that beforehand...

Comment: You could also try ARB_sync with a host side timer. Though that might be trickier.

Comment: @ronag same problem as glFinish, it forces an synchronisation point

Comment: @niktehpui: Not necessarily. You just need to query the fence state, not wait for it. Set fence, glFlush and then poll state.

Comment: Neither `glFinish` nor fences will do what he needs. Fences are not guarantees to be accurate with regard to time. You can test the fence, but there's no guarantee that the GPU hasn't finished. There's no requirement that the fence *immediately* is set at the moment the GPU finishes with it. Thus, your timings will be inaccurate. Same goes for `glFinish`; there's no guarantee of timing.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Though you are correct, I think that's the best he can to without "GL_ARB_timer_query".

Comment: @ronag: A timing mechanism who's accuracy is questionable at best is of no use at all. If you can't trust what your "timer" says, then you can't reasonably take action based on it.

Comment: Timing based on `glFinish` or fences isn't *worthless*, as it does provide an upper bound on the time required. Depending on the implementation, it may even be a pretty good and reliable upper bound. Whether that is useful for the task at hand is not something we can evaluate, since the question doesn't say what the information is to be used for.